# Symfony 3.4 translated routes requirements (JMSi18nRoutingBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, internationalization, symfony-3.4

I am using JMSi18nRouting Bundle. And i wonder if its possible to create 1 route configuration allowing this:

```
/de/neu --> ok
/en/new --> ok
/en/neu --> nok (404)
```

Route annotation looks like this:

```
* @Route("/{slug}", name="category_new", requirements={"slug" : "new|neu"})
```

So i think what i need is a requirement for {slug} based on the locale, something like this:

```
requirements={"slug" : "{ "de" : "neu", "en" : "new" }"}
```

Somebody if its possible with my setup?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that could be configured in that version of Symfony, but according to https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing, it's possible to do so in a more recent version. Your route configuration would look like:

```
/**
 * @Route({
 *     "de": "/neu",
 *     "en": "/new"
 * }, name="category_new")
 */
```

Comment: Hey Nico, thank you. No it isn't, thats why they say new in symfony 4.1 ;) And i am searching for requirements based on locales...

Comment: ...but as you are using 3.4 already, which should report all deprecated features between 3.4 and 4.0, you could try to upgrade the Symfony core and see whether this new feature helps. Running such an upgrade should be done from time to time anyways ;)